# Cache is not defined error

Tags: javascript

```
function example(str) {
 var cache = ( str != "" ) ? str : null;
}

example("something");
alert(cache); // cache is not defined
```

On alert, it says cache is not defined. How to make it so that after calling a function, cache will be saved and I could invoke it like alert(cache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Self-memorizing functions
>
> Memorization is the process of building a function that’s capable of
>   remembering its previously computed values. This can markedly increase
>   performance by avoiding needless complex computations that have
>   already been performed.

```
function foo(str) {
    if (!foo.cache) {
        foo.cache = ( typeof str !== undefined ) ? str : null;
    }
}

foo("something");

alert(foo.cache);
```

Comment: A fine answer, but a little bit of overkill right?  What is the value of foo remembering something here?  Memorization is for performance not basic value passing.  Nevertheless, another fun way of sharing state.

Answer (score 2):

The variable 'cache' is defined in the function example and not outside that scope so alert does not have access to it.  Please look at other similar questions, example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113894/variables-from-anonymous-function/22114051#22114051 ; not 10 minutes ago.  I would also recommend reading on Javascript especially how variable scope works.  It is very similar to most programming languages but funky in a couple other, ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx

Not recommended, but a quick answer is:

```
var cache;
function example(str) {
 cache = ( str != "" ) ? str : null;
}

example("something");
alert(cache);
```

Comment: or if he can get rid of the `cache` var and use `return` instead http://jsfiddle.net/xfmj2/

Comment: Most certainly can do a number of things.  My link highlights several of the normal options.

Answer (score 2):

`cache` is a `local` variable to `example` `function`. I suggest to use a `namespace` instead of a `global` `variable`. If it wont be a global variable, be free to use a classic `var` declaration.

so:

```
var app = app || {}; //define namespace
app.cache = "";

function example(str) {
  app.cache = str != "" ? str : null; 
  //i guess it should equal to:
  // cache = str ? str : null;
}

console.log(str); //similar to alert, but logs in developers tool (chrome) or       firebug(FFx)
```

ps: I suggest the use of `console.log()` (or `debug`) instead of `alert()`. It's more comfortable than  `alert()`

Answer (score 1):

Define `cache` outside `function exmaple()`

```
var cache;
function example(str) {
   cache = ( str != "" ) ? str : null;
}
```

When you define inside the function it's scope would be finished inside it, so you can not access `cache` from outside of function in your case.